# A function that accepts only compile time known expressions?

Tags: c++, templates, operators, compile-time-constant

Compile time expressions are good because you can use them to specialize templates. So for example, tuples can be accessed by using a compile time expression with the `std::get` method.

```
std::cout << std::get<0>(my_tuple) << std::endl;
```

Now, the above expression is pretty ugly. I am trying to develop some sort of tuples myself (hoping to make it to turn them into compile time dictionaries), so that, say, they expose a method in the form:

```
my_dict.get<0>();
```

Now, what I would like to do is to substitute that with a [] operator. I was wondering if that was even possible at all. First of all, I wouldn't know how to select only constant, compile time known expressions as parameters for my operator. Moreover, the return type would depend on the value of the constant expression.

With a define, however, I can get closer to what I want with something like

```
#define item(x) get<x>()
```

so that I can then use

```
my_dict.item(0)
```

Is there a way to get something better than this?

Comment: I don't understand your goal, at all. Accept the argument only as a template argument. Problem solved...

Comment: User-defined literals to easily define `std::integral_constant` objects? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8450185699979be

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you can't quite turn argument of `operator[]` into a template argument.

Comment: @doublep: So don't use `operator[]`.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-proposals/RdAK-0RyiY0/4yUZoKepHYQJ

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses types to convey the index, which are then passed to `operator[]`, which extracts the index.

```
template<std::size_t n>
using idx_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, n>;
template<std::size_t n>
idx_t<n> idx;

constexpr int square( int x ) { return x*x; }
constexpr int power( int base, size_t pow ) {
  return (pow==0)?1:
    (pow==1)?base:
      (
        square(power(base, pow/2))
          *( (pow%2)?base:1 )
      );
}

template<char... cs>
struct helper:idx_t<0>{};
template<char c0, char...cs>
struct helper<c0, cs...>:idx_t< (c0-'0') * power(10, sizeof...(cs)) + helper<cs...>{} > {};

template<char...cs>
constexpr idx_t< helper<cs...>{} > operator""_idx() { return {}; }

struct foo {
  template<std::size_t n>
  void operator[](idx_t<n>) const {
    char arr[n];
    std::cout << sizeof(arr) << '\n';
  }
};
```

There are 3 (equivalent, up to syntactic sugar) ways to use this:

```
foo f;
f[idx_t<1>{}];
f[idx<2>];
f[3_idx];
f[1337_idx];
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bae3672a55c2dbf).  Support for `0xff_idx` etc is left as an exercise.